# How to Download all Files listed in a directory from SFTP in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, filesystems, sftp, laravel-filesystem

I am new to laravel. I am making an application in which I check a directory that is being served on an SFTP. By looking into the documentation I was successfully able to list all the file names inside a directory hosted on that SFTP.

My next goal is to save all those in a local folder `public/InputFiles` but how do I do that? I have tried several combinations but none has helped.

Here is what I have done. In `config/filesystem.php` I have

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/InputFiles',
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => 'exampleHost.com',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
    ]
```

In my controller I have this function

```
public function getFilesFromFtp()
{
    //all files are present inside 'outgoing' folder
    $file_list = Storage::disk('sftp')->allFiles('outgoing/');
    
    foreach ($file_list as $key => $value) {
        # code...

        //output the name of the files
        $this->printVariable(str_replace("outgoing/", "", $value));
        Storage::disk('public')->put(str_replace("outgoing/", "", $value), Storage::disk('sftp')->download($value));
        
    }
```

For example I had a file named as `sample.txt` inside the outgoing folder on SFTP. Inside this file I had text as `Sample text`.

By using the above method, I was able to see the `sample.txt` file made in desired location but its contents were as follows

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
> Cache-Control:       no-cache, private
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.txt"
> Content-Length:      12
> Content-Type:        text/plain
> Date:                Thu, 19 Apr 2018 10:35:10 GMT

This is not what I want. I actually want to save the file as it is just like on SFTP. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changed the line to

```
Storage::disk('public')->put(str_replace("outgoing/", "", $value), Storage::disk('sftp')->get($value));
```

So basically I am getting file from sftp and putting it in local directory. No need to download it.